# How to make these elements using createDocumentFragment?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have to append these elements times by length of json from api. but I'm new to createDocumentFragment so I'm not sure what to do. HTML Code below is what I have to append multiple times, and example js code.

```
<div class="column is-3 vid">
  <div class="panel">
    <p class="is-marginless"><img src="imgSrc"/></p>
    <div class="panel vidInfo"><a href="#" class="vid-title"><span>text</span></a>
      <div class="columns has-text-centered">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="panel-item reddit-ups"><i class="fa fa-reddit-alien fa-2x"></i>2 </div>
          <div class="panel-item reddit-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x"></i>2d </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**js code**

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

 for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
     //append elements like html code above in body.    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the existing `html` within a `<script>` element at `document`, with `type` set to `text/html`, then call get `.innerHTML` of element, use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` with `"beforeend"` as first parameter to append `html` string to `document.body`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script id="template" type="text/html">
    <div class="column is-3 vid">
      <div class="panel">
        <p class="is-marginless"><img src="imgSrc" /></p>
        <div class="panel vidInfo"><a href="#" class="vid-title"><span>text</span></a>
          <div class="columns has-text-centered">
            <div class="column">
              <div class="panel-item reddit-ups"><i class="fa fa-reddit-alien fa-2x"></i>2 </div>
              <div class="panel-item reddit-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x"></i>2d </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  var template = document.getElementById("template");
  var html = template.innerHTML;
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    //append elements like html code above in body. 
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
  } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```